Confusion about multiplying probabilities using random variables
While reviewing some probability theory I stumbled upon something I did not fully understand. Suppose we have a problem consisting of three independent Bernoulli trials with random variable $X$ denoting the number of successes. In the problem statement we are given the probability $\mathbb{P}_0(\{1\}) = p$ (the success of a trial), which axiomatically must mean $\mathbb{P}_0(\{0\}) = 1 - p$, but this is in the sample space $\Omega = \{0, 1\}$. The sample space concerning the problem is the set $\Omega^3$ consisting of all 3-tuples of the set $\Omega$. Now, if we wanted to know $\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega^3\mid X(\omega) = 0\}) = \mathbb{P}(\{(0,0,0)\})$ we can, as if by magic, simply say $\mathbb{P}(\{(0,0,0)\} = (\mathbb{P}_0(\{0\}))^3 = (1-p)^3$. Which is justified how exactly?
If I consider the same problem using "vanilla" subsets of $\Omega^3$, we can define $A_i \colon$ the event that the $i$th trial is a success, where $i = 1, 2, 3$. Suddenly it becomes justified because $\mathbb{P}(A_i) = p$ and also $\mathbb{P}(A_1'\cap A_2'\cap A_3') = \mathbb{P}(\{(0, 0, 0)\}) = (1-p)^3$ by independence.
It seems like I'm just really confused about how to think about random variables. When solving a problem, are you supposed to think about them in a similar way as I did above where the set generated by the random variable condition $\{(0,0,0)\}$ was really an intersection of subsets that I could put some "sense" on? The book I'm using really just handwaved this and offered no thorough explanation.

You have 3 random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ that all have a Bernoulli distribution. Considering that you are talking about underlying events, consider the probability space $(\Omega = \{0,1\}, \mathcal{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega), P)$, where $P(1) = p = 1-P(0)$ uniquely determines a probability measure on this measurable space. The mappings $X_i:\Omega \to \Omega$ such that $X_i(\omega)=\omega$, $i=1,2,3$ are now trivially Bernoulli random variables. Because we assume the random variables to be independent, we can model them by considering the product space $(\Omega^3, \mathcal{P}(\Omega^3), P^3)$, where $P^3$ is the unique probability measure such that $P(A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3) = P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3),~A_i \in \mathcal{F},~i=1,2,3$. (You see why this is equivalent to the independence assumption on the $X_i$?) The number of successes of these Bernoulli trials can now be described by the random variable
$$
X(\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3) = \omega_1+\omega_2+\omega_3.
$$
or $X = X_1+X_2+X_3$ if we consider $X_i$ to be the $i$th coordinate projection of $X$. Now,
$$
P^3(\omega:X(\omega)=0) = P^3((0,0,0)) = P^3(\{0\} \times \{0\} \times \{0\}) = P(0)P(0)P(0) = P(0)^3.
$$
Your subset approach also works, but you need to be able to argue why the random variable's independence implies these subsets' independence.
